# My random number generator is printing duplicate numbers

Tags: c++, random

I'm working on a program that uses a function that would generate 2 random integers that I would later use to ask the user to add and figure out the sum. For the time being, I came across a problem in which it's duplicating the same number.

Here's the program thus far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;


/*
This function generates a random integer
between 0 and max_int
*/
int get_rand_int(int max_int){
    srand(time(0));
    return int(rand()) % max_int;
}


This program generates random addition problems
with integers between 0 and 100


int main(){
    int num1 = get_rand_int(101);
    int num2 = get_rand_int(101);
    cout << num1 << endl;
    cout << num2 << endl;
```

Please note this this is a homework problem my teacher assigned. He provided us with the skeleton and we're trying to fill in the blanks. I have a feeling the problem lies within the srand section of my function but that was part of my teacher's work so I'm not sure whether I need to touch that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You *know* this has been asked before...

Comment: @EricJ.: While I agree, the link you've provided is about C#. A better choice might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

Comment: Same exact issue.  Most languages in fact share this issue.  Feel free to vote to close as a duplicate of the one you provide though.

Comment: I apologize that this might be a duplicate question. I read those other questions and saw how srand is the issue. I just want to make sure that's the only problem with it duplicating since my professor was the one that provided that srand in the skeleton program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `srand` initializes the random sequence with the result of `time`. However, `time` changes only once per second! This means that if you call your function twice in a one-second delay, you get the same number.

One solution is to call `srand` just once, at the beginning of your program (in the `main` function, for instance).

Comment: I thought so. Guess I need to tell me teacher he messed up! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You must seed the random generator only once in your program,

```
srand(time(0)); // this must happen only once, at the beginning of main()
```

You now seed it inside the function `get_rand_int`, and call the function twice in a very short amount of time. The seed ends up being the same, so you get the same sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Call the srand(time(0)) in the main to set the current time only once to use random generation instantly.

```
int main(){
srand(time(0));
int num1 = get_rand_int(101);                          
int num2 = get_rand_int(101);
cout << num1 << endl;
cout << num2 << endl;
```

}